# Filling Polygons based on values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, polygon, shapefile

I'm new to python and polygons. i was asked to create a dictionary from a dataframe, which contains population sums for each state in the US from the year 2016.

```
population_mean = population_data_all.groupby(by=['NAME'], as_index=False)[['POPEST2016_CIV']].sum()
population_dict = population_mean.set_index('NAME').T.to_dict('list')
population_dict
```

Sample output of the dictionary:

> {'Alabama': [4849650],  'Alaska': [720195],  'Arizona': [6911889], 
>   'Arkansas': [2982997],  'California': [39091453],  'Colorado':
>   [5506673],  'Connecticut': [3568865],  'Delaware': [948534]}

and then i was asked to Get a US states geojson file 
Sources - ArcGIS shapefile of US 50 states + DC (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5)

and was then asked to plot it and change the color of Alaska to red based on the shapefile, which i did using this code.

```
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca()
BLUE = '#5599ff'
RED = '#FF0000'

for feature in data['features']:
    geometry = feature['geometry']
    state = feature['properties']['STATE_NAME']
    if geometry['type'] == 'Polygon':
        poly = geometry
        ppatch = PolygonPatch(poly, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE,  alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
        ax.add_patch(ppatch)
    elif geometry['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
        for polygon in geometry['coordinates'][0]:
            if state == 'Alaska':
                poly = Polygon(polygon)
                ppatch = PolygonPatch(poly, fc=RED, ec=RED, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
                ax.add_patch(ppatch)
            else:
                poly = Polygon(polygon)
                ppatch = PolygonPatch(poly, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
                ax.add_patch(ppatch)

    else:
        print('Don\'t know how to draw :', geometry['type'])



ax.axis('scaled')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

However, iam lost and need help on how to use the values from the dictionary above to color the polygons. for example, using a color map, so each state gets a color based on it's population.

thanks!

Comment: I think you can simplify this a lot using [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html)

Comment: Yes, what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said: `geopandas`. You'll load the SHP file using `geopandas`, add a `population` column from your dictionary (merge based on the state name), then you can just plot that column with `df.population.plot()`. Check out [the examples](http://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_with_geoplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-plotting-with-geoplot-py).